# Bell on every output using Putty

Tags: linux, putty

I use a putty server that prints to standard output whenever I am idle for too long. I would like to configure Putty to activate the bell each time this occurs; I have set up my bell config in putty, and I know that a bell can be triggered with

```
echo -ne '\007'
```

So I suppose the best thing to do would be to create a background process that appends this character to everything printed to standard output.

How can I do this?

```
You have been idle for quite a long time.
danie01: You've been idle for 1031 min.
You'll be logged off in 3600 sec.
Please: Type something into a terminal 
        or you'll be kicked off.
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the activity monitoring feature in GNU screen?

Comment: I can't access root on this server, so I can't install anything.

Comment: When I have not send a command for... an hour, I think? The server prints to my console alerting me that this has happened.

Comment: Do you *really* want a bell or would you rather turn on keepalives? https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keepalive

Comment: I would like to have a bell.

Comment: AFAIK, Putty has no scripting or character remapping. It was discussed a while back on the putty wish list but I don't believe it ever happened. Putty is open source, however and if you really want this, you could always create a patched copy for yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to write a Linux script to redirect all standard output and append a bell to it? Does not need to be a putty-specific solution. Even a script to redirect everything to a log file would let me tail that log file.

Comment: You can do this with `exec > >(sed -ue 's/$/\a/')` but it has many ugly side effects and I doubt your warning program writes to the shell's stdout

Comment: Do you know what process "prints to stdout" when you're idle? can you provide whatever it prints? AFAIK, SSH just disconnects when exceeding the server's ClientAliveInterval.

Comment: I have added the output to my question. I have no clue what process is printing this.

Comment: I actually can use GNU screen.

Comment: let me try to understand what the setup is. You have a `putty` client (not server), presumably on Windows. The server to which you connect (which is likely a GNU/Linux-based OS) is monitoring activity and warns you on idle. This probably means that the warning is sent directly to your shell's TTY via the 'write' command. Is this correct? Not sure that 'screen' will work in this case (write will likely reach the pseudo-tty created by ssh-server and not screen's own pseudo-tty, as screen writes to the former, so it is always more up-to-date and becomes the default target of 'write').